# Is there any kazza or replacement for Jummah (Friday) Prayer

Tags: salat, jumuah, salat-qada

Sometimes due to school or any other problem Friday prayer missed just as other prayers, but there is kazza for other prayers.

I want to know that Is there any replacement or kazza for Friday Prayer?

One week has one Friday and missed Friday Prayer can't be done on another Friday.

If there is not any replacement for Friday prayer than Is it punished?

Answer (score 2):

There's no qada' for Jumuah prayer as you may only perform the two raka'a in a mosque where the Jumu'ah is held following the imam -who in best case held the sermon- afterwards, if you came late for example **you must pray the dhohr prayer instead if you didn't catch at least one raka'a with the congregation**. An exception is the hanafi madhhab where you may still pray only two raka'as even if you caught the imam after the ruku' of the second raka'a.

Note that jumuah at the time of the prophet () was only prescribed for citizens (people in cities) that's why our prophet () in his hajjat al-Wada' حجة الوداع  on the day of 'Arafah -which was a Friday-  prayed dhohr instead of Jumuah and that's also why women usually pray dhohr instead as they are not asked to perform jumuah based on the authentic hadith saying:

> The Friday prayer in congregation is a necessary duty for every Muslim, with four exceptions; a slave, a woman, a boy, and a sick person. ([Sunan abi Dawod](https://www.sunnah.com/abudawud/2/678))

Traveling people also don't need to pray jumuah. Imam al-Bukhari in his sahih compiled a chapter he entitled: "[Chapter: To offer Jumu'ah prayer and Khutba in villages and towns](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/11/17)" Ibn Hajar al-'Asqalani in his fath al-Barry commented this saying: that this title is an indication on the dispute (among scholars) on whether Jumuah in rural area's is prescribed or not. Most scholars consider being settled or the existence of brick built buildings as a condition for Jumuah, some also consider praying it in a mosque as a necessary condition.

Finally note that is sinful and highly discouraged to miss the jumuah prayer for a male who is able to perform it -meaning a male who has no valid excuse- (for more than three weeks) based on ahadith such as:

- > People must cease to neglect the Friday prayer or Allah will seal their hearts and then they will be among the negligent. ([Sahih Muslim](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/7/52))
- > Yahya related to me from Malik that Safwan ibn Sulaym said, "If anyone omits jumua three times without reason or illness, Allah will set a seal on his heart." (Malik said, "I don't know if it was from the Messenger of Allah, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, or not.")  ([Muwatta' Malik](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/502450))
- > "Allah's Messenger said: 'Whoever neglects the Friday prayer three times (in a row) without an excuse, then Allah sets a seal upon his heart.'" ([Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/4/13))

**Conclusion:**
Jumuah prayer must be performed on time in congregation, if one missed it or has a valid excuse for not praying it, there's no qada' prayer, but one must pray the regular dhohr instead.

See also the fatwas [#79667](https://islamqa.info/en/79667) and [#11556](https://islamqa.info/en/11556) on islamqa.

Comment: So what can we do for the missed prayers?

Comment: @RahatBatool as said if you missed it you pray your normal dhohr instead!

Comment: Due to school or work I am busy from 8:00 to 5:00. I pray kazza for dhohr and asar. So for the missed Friday prayer kaza dhohr is acceptable?

Comment: @RahatBatool If I said yes I would have spoken out a fatwa, I'm no scholar. I don't know your circumstances. If you have a chance to join the congregation you should better do so, you should also pray each prayer on time, if you can't (Allah knows best) or had not done so (this is sinful if there's no acceptable reason) you still must pray your prayers according the view of the majority of scholars. So praying dhohr or dhohr as qada' is the minimum you could do to accomplish your duty!